# phpspec test logic in constructor

Tags: phpspec

I have a logic like this

```
 public function __construct(DataFetcherInterface $fetcher, Alert $alert) {
   $this->data = $fetcher->getData();
   foreach($this->data as $info) {
       try {
           $fetcher->assoicateAddress($info);
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           $alert->sendAlert($info)
       }
   }
}
```

and I want to test logic here, for example if `sendAlert()` will be called in case of exception.

```
    public function it_should_throw_exception(
        DataFetcherInterface $fetcher,
        Alert $alert
    ): void {
        $fetcher->getData()->willReturn(
        // data here
        )->shouldBeCalled();
        
        $fetcher->assoicateAddress(
        // data here
       )->willThrow(Excpetion::class)->shouldBeCalled();

        $alert->sendAlert()->shouldBeCalled(
        // data here
       );

        $this->beConstructedWith($fetcher, $logger); // <== not sure how to do it here
    }
```

and it's not working, error:

```
 - it should throw exception
      some predictions failed:
      DataFetcherInterface\P3:
        No calls have been made that match:
            DataFetcherInterface\P3->getData()
          but expected at least one.
```

I know php spec is for TDD, and I should start from tests, but at the moment I start adding tests I already had some come, for new code I'll use TDD approach.

Is it a bad practice to have such logic in constructor?? I have other methods in the class as well, but I want it to be instantiated with all needed data, and I'm using `Visitor` pattern to get all data while initializing object

Comment: In order to help you I'd need the following classes: `DataFetcherInterface` and `Alert`. Also the code for `__construct` is wrong, you are missing an `}` before `catch`, and you have a typo in `assoicateAddress`.

Comment: sorry for typo, fixing, Why you need `DataFetcherInterface` and `Alert`, I'm mocking them in the spec? as you can see I have a mock form `DataFetcherInterface`, which telling that `getData` method should be called and return some datat (I omit actuall data to reduce amount of code), but phpspec telling that `getData` have not been made, but in the actual class I'm making that call. I'm not sure but I think phpspec's `beConstructedWith` not running actual constructor logic of the actual class

Comment: In order to help you I need to reproduce the error. To reproduce the error I need the full code.

Comment: Okay, I'll add it